# Why am I not able to convert a string when using non-ASCII characters?

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii

I encountered a small issue in Python. I'm not able to print a string containing the "é" character. I'll explain:

```
  for actor in show.actor_objects:
     f.write(u"\n  <actor>")
     f.write(u"\n    <name>{0}</name>".format(str(actor.Name).encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
     f.write(u"\n    <role>{0}</role>".format(str(actor.Role).encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
     f.write(u"\n  </actor>")
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
root@vroum:21:26:44#~:?1# python test.py -s 2 -n Kaamelott -o outfile.txt -f 0 -l 50  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 104, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "test.py", line 99, in main
    f.write(u"\n    <role>{0}</role>".format(str(actor.Role).encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I resolve this? I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: `decode` is the one that turns bytestrings into Unicode strings. `encode` is for the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're passing a unicode string to the str() function (In Python 2 where str is a bytes string). If you just get rid of the call to str it should work:

```
f.write(u"\n    <name>{0}</name>".format(actor.Name.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
f.write(u"\n    <role>{0}</role>".format(actor.Role.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
```

Using encode('ascii', 'ignore') will completely drop the unicode characters however. You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
f.write(u"\n    <name>{0}</name>".format(actor.Name).encode('UTF-8'))
f.write(u"\n    <role>{0}</role>".format(actor.Role).encode('UTF-8'))
```

Comment: The ".encode('ascii', 'ignore')" solution worked for me. I can drop characters without pb ^^.

Thanks for your help guys :)